# Angular - how to route array params to a new modal component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, modal-dialog

I have some results coming from an array in a card. I'd like to open a new modal component in which I'd pass some of these results by clicking on a button located in the card.
I know how to route params by using `routerLink`, I know how to open a modal but I don't see how I could both open the modal AND routing array params inside..

To make it clearer, here is my HTML page (*item.name* would be the param to route) :

```
<div class="row card-group">
    <div class="col-4"  *ngFor="let item of myArray">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" >
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h3>
          <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{item.name}}</h5>
          <button (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></button>
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the TS component :

```
openModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent,
      {
        scrollable: true,
        windowClass: 'myCustomModalClass'
      });

    let data = {
      item: '' // Would be the param to route
    }

    modalRef.componentInstance.fromParent = data;
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    }, (reason) => {
    });
  }
```

Comment: store in an auxiliar variable the "param":https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information and use this variable when open the modal

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for your answer. I will try but how can I use the *item.name* param to insert in something like ```this.name = params['name'];```